# PG::NumericValueOutOfRange: ERROR: value "34531513513513" is out of range for type integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6

I needed to test the creation of a record in the database. I went to the page with the form, randomly entered the value "34531513513513" in the title field. Selected values from select for belongs_to. And in the end I clicked on "Add".

As a result, the record was added to the database, and the controller action made me a redirect to index where I received this error:

> ActiveRecord::RangeError - PG::NumericValueOutOfRange: ERROR:  value "34531513513513" is out of range for type integer

The error is caused by this code:

```rb
scope :order_by_title, (lambda do
  order(Arel.sql("left(lower(posts.title), 1), substring(posts.title, '\\d+')::int NULLS FIRST, posts.title"))
end)
```

Specifically:

```sql
substring(posts.title, '\\d+')::int
```

Tell me, please, how can I fix this code? But the sorting logic needs to be preserved.

*P. S. I understand that for me it is most likely a very rare bug in production (because with 99% probability I will not use such large numbers in titles). But I still wonder how to solve this problem.*

Comment: This is a postgres issue, not really related to Rails or ActiveRecord

Comment: The postgres `INTEGER` type can store a 4 byte signed integer ranging from `-2,147,483,648` to `+2,147,483,647`. That would explain the out of range error.

Comment: I think you can probably figure out the appropriate datatype to cast to from [Here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html) Hint: it is unlikely you will have a number larger than 9,223,372,036,854,775,807

Comment: @engineersmnky Sounds like a solution to the problem. Thank you.